# Анимация сворачивающейся коробки

Tags: javascript, css, css3, svg, css-animation

Интересуют примеры реализации сворачивания-разворачивания коробки по её  развёртке (CSS, CSS3, Canvas, SVG), буду очень признателен..

Comment: смотрите теги transform и читайте анимацию SVG очень полезный и понятный цикл лекций по SVG - http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/1063/210/lecture/5424

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я знаю, что на нашем ресурсе не принято посылать автора вопроса в Google :)
Всё же,  как то надо научиться задавать более развернутые вопросы, с примерами, с попытками, как-то самому порешать задачу.
Может быть еще автор не имеет достаточного опыта работы в поисковиках. Искал, но не нашёл.
Поэтому, может быть вот так сделать?

Набираете в строке поиска Google, Codepen, Stackoverflow - `cube opening animation`
и...

[How to use CSS animations to create a cube's opening like in the picture?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41427846/7394871)

[svg animation - opening a cube](https://codepen.io/yungtiec/)

[Creating a cube opening animation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41011267/7394871)

[css3 transforms to simulate a present opening](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34069581/7394871)

[rotate3d shorthand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28911367/7394871)

[Rotate Cube](http://dabblet.com/gist/4600036)

[Simple Opening SCSS Cubes](https://codepen.io/unmeshpro/pen/nlGBa)

### Update

Перевел топик по первой ссылке, может быть ещё кому-нибудь, кроме автора вопроса, будет полезен [ответ с stackoferflow.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/756160/28748).

Comment: Спасибо, что не послали  в Google :)
В этих примерах я нашёл интересовавший меня момент.Спасибо.

Comment: @СергейСуворов Благодарю Может зададите новый вопрос про анимацию куба, тем более, что пишите, что нашли в ссылках интересное решение. Чем подробнее будет вопрос, тем большая вероятность, что найдется решение. Лучше с кодом, пусть не работающим, можно картинки, пусть даже будет, криво от руки, но будет однозначно понятно, что вы хотите.

Comment: Ох..И хотел бы - но моё задание из области "пойди туда-не знаю-куда"(я должен написать что-то вроде мини-библиотеки, к-я будет сворачивать разные развёртки -  анимация развёртки куба всего лишь момент из моего "квеста") огромное Вам спасибо, но на данном этапе подробнее задать вопрос не могу - всё в процессе..осмысления.