# Как использовать CSS для анимации открытия куба

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, css-animation

В моем проекте при открытии домашней страницы,  должна запускаться анимация CSS,- открывание сторон куба.
 После завершения анимации положение сторон куба, должно быть похоже на первый фрагмент картинки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```css
.sk-folding-cube {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  -webkit-animation: sk-foldCubeAngle 2.4s 0.5 linear both;
  animation: sk-foldCubeAngle 2.4s 0.5 linear both;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube2 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(90deg);
  transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(90deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube3 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(180deg);
  transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(180deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube4 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(270deg);
  transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(270deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube5 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(360deg);
  transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube5 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(360deg);
  transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube2:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube3:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube4:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
  animation-delay: 0.9s;
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube5:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube6:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes sk-foldCubeAngle {
  0%, 10% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
    transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25%,
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
    transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
    transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes sk-foldCubeAngle {
  0%, 10% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
    transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25%,
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
    transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
    transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Open Cube</title>
  <h1>Apertura Cubo</h1>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="sk-folding-cube">
    <a href="http://google.com"><div class="sk-cube1 sk-cube"></div></a>
    <div class="sk-cube2 sk-cube"></div>
    <div class="sk-cube4 sk-cube"></div>
    <div class="sk-cube3 sk-cube"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Как я могу это сделать?

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41424308/7394871)

Comment: @Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41424308/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Судя по описанию, и   представленному изображению, мне кажется, что вы пытаетесь создать анимацию открытия плоского куба, где каждая грань куба открывается одна за другой и анимация заканчивается в положении, как показано на первом фрагменте рисунка.

Возможно, этот эффект можно будет улучшить, изменив ваш текущий код, но я нашел его немного запутанным, и поэтому создал  собственную версию плоского куба.

**Объяснение:**

- Сначала создайте куб с шестью гранями (один элемент `div` для каждой
  грани).       Я сделал лицевую сторону, как дочерний элемент  левой
  грани куба, потому что передняя грань должна быть открыта с левой
  стороны левой грани.
- Каждая грань представляет собой квадрат размером 50 х 50 пикселей,
  свойства `transform` и `transform-origin` которых, заданы таким
  образом, чтобы они создавали куб.
- Анимация открытия прикрепляется к каждой из граней и добавляется
  задержка в зависимости от того, в какой последовательности они должны
  открываться.
- В демоверсии правая грань открывается первой, и поэтому она не имеет
  задержки, нижняя грань открывается второй и поэтому имеет задержку в
  `1сек.` (равную времени анимации правой стороны), верхняя грань
  открывается третьей и  имеет задержку в `2сек`  (равной сумме
  анимаций предыдущих двух граней) и так далее.
- Задняя грань не имеет анимации, так как её вообще не нужно
  открывать;)

```css
.cube {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.cube div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.back {
  background: rebeccapurple;
}
.right {
  background: tomato;
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  transform-origin: right;
  animation: open-y 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}
.bottom {
  background: crimson;
  transform: rotateX(270deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  animation: open-x 1s 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}
.top {
  background: indianred;
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transform-origin: top;
  animation: open-x 1s 2s ease-in-out forwards;
}
.left {
  background: yellowgreen;
  transform: rotateY(270deg);
  transform-origin: left;
  animation: open-y 1s 3s ease-in-out forwards;
}
.front {
  background: chocolate;
  transform: rotateY(270deg);
  transform-origin: right;
  animation: open-y 1s 3s ease-in-out forwards;
}
@keyframes open-y {
  to {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}
@keyframes open-x {
  to {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cube">
  <div class="back"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="left">
    <div class="front"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Примечание*

Конечно возможно добиться аналогичного эффекта и другими способами, а также сделать их более реалистичными, но это, скорее всего, потребует значительного количества  `transforms translate`, дополнительных настроек `keyframe` для анимаций и т.д. - короче говоря, намного более сложный код.

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41427846/7394871)